# Multiple inputs and getting output at once

Tags: java

I intend to find the number of palindromes inbetween the given numbers, The variable 't' decides the number of test cases. For example, if t=2 I give the input as :

```
2
12 23(in the next line)
56 78(in the next line)
Where the output would be:
1
2 (next line)
```

But with my code after the input is given as :

```
2
12 23
```

I get the output as 1 and then I should proceed to give the next test case

How can I give both the test cases once?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Checkall {
    public int check_all(int a, int b) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int y = a; y <= b; y++) {
            int z = y;
            int d = 0;
            while (z > 0) {
                d = d * 10 + z % 10;
                z /= 10;
            }
            if (d == y) c++;
        }
        return c;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
        //System.out.println("Enter the limits");
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int s = 1; s <= t; s++) {
            Scanner scn;
            scn = new Scanner(System. in );
            int a = scn.nextInt();
            int b = scn.nextInt();
            Checkall p = new Checkall();
            p.check_all(a, b);
            System.out.print(p.check_all(a, b));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not an issue for most automated judges :)

Comment: Do you have some errors?, or do you simply want us to solve your problem?

Comment: I don't have an error, I need the problem to be solved

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
    //System.out.println("Enter the limits");
    int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int[][] limits = new int[t][2];
    // 1st read all limits
    for (int s = 1; s <= t; s++) {
        Scanner scn;
        scn = new Scanner(System. in );
        limits[s-1][0] = scn.nextInt();
        limits[s-1][1] = scn.nextInt();
    }
    // 2nd process all of them.
    for ( int s = 1; s <= t; s++ ) {
        Checkall p = new Checkall();
        p.check_all(limits[s-1][0], limits[s-1][1]);
        System.out.print(p.check_all(limits[s-1][0], limits[s-1][1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: This code worked fine on my editor, but elsewhere(hackerearth.com) it doesn't. @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos

Answer (score 0):

For debugging these formatting issues, using your terminal for both input and output isn't a great idea. You can write the input to a file:

```
$ cat > in.txt
2
1 2
3 4
^C # press Control and C here
```

and then feed that into your program:

```
$ java Checkall < in.txt
```

Now you'll only see the output!

Answer (score 0):

Read all values and add it to a two dimensional array.

```
int[][] values=new int[t][2]
```

add values in each iteration

```
values[s][0]=first number
values[s][1]=second number
```

after scanning iteration finished call calculation method for each value set

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scanner nextInt` carefully:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Enter the limits");

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    int t = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());

    for (int s = 0; s < t; s++) {
        int a = scn.nextInt();
        int b = scn.nextInt();
        scn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(new Checkall().check_all(a, b));
    }
}
```